# How can i add Bootstrap carousel gradient

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

Hello I' am using bootstrap and i created a slider, but I can't watch slider gradient in left or right side so can you help me please ?

I use bootstrap default slider, code is given below,

```
<div id="carouselId" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselId" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselId" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselId" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="img/slider1.png" alt="First slide">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="img/slider2.png" alt="Second slide">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="img/slider3.png"  alt="Third slide">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselId" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselId" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Is "gradient" the right word for what you're after? Also, why do you have tags for two Bootstrap versions? Pick one, please.

Comment: please, add full snippet to edit it easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap has a gradient by default, i think you're using pieces of code from two different bootstrap versions.

This is a default bootstrap carousel code:

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

With addition, you can modify the default gradient with:

```
a.carousel-control:hover, a.carousel-control.right:hover {
 background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(250, 0, 0, 0) 0px, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
}
a.carousel-control.left:hover{
 background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(250, 0, 0, 0) 0px, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
}
```

See a working example on the same default code with only one image:
https://jsfiddle.net/a0jn3yz2/17/

Comment: you're welcome! If it helps you, mark it as solution to help other users to find the answer fast. Good luck with your project!